# how to convert String to message in java mail api?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

how to convert String to message in java mail api?

Comment: Have you tried googling e.g. for "javamail tutorial"?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `MimeMessage` constructor which accepts an `InputStream`. (See the [JavaMail documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage%28javax.mail.Session,%20java.io.InputStream%29))

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mySession, 
        new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes()));
```

Comment: How about the other way? How can I convert MIME message to String ?

Comment: e.g. with org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're after. Perhaps [The Quintessential Program to Send E-Mail [J2EE]](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.mail/SendApp.html) helps?

Key method being [`msg.setText(content)`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

If the String contains the message body, just take or create a Message object (like a `MimeMessage`) and use the `setText`method.

Otherwise, if the String holds a 'full' email, you'll have to separate header and body (from the String) and could use the `addHeaderLine()` method to recreate a message header.